# Undefined reference to functions from pcap.h

Tags: c, java-native-interface, static-linking, pcap, cl.exe

I write RTP sniffer and need to create dll to use it in my java project as native. I use cl.exe

```
cl.exe -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\include\win32"  -I "..\..\lib\WpdPack\Include"  -I "..\..\lib\WpdPack\Include\bin" -I "..\..\lib\WpdPack\Lib\x64"  -D"WIN32" -D"WPCAP" -D"HAVE_REMOTE" -LD "rtpnative.c"   -Fe"rtpnative.dll" -link "..\..\lib\WpdPack\Lib\x64\wpcap.lib" "..\..\lib\WpdPack\Lib\x64\Packet.lib"
```

but at the linking step I receive such errors for all functions I use in my *.c file

> Error! E2028: pcap_lookupdev_ is an undefined reference

Please give me an advice how to solve this problem.

Comment: If you truly mean "pcap_lookupdev_ is an undefined reference", with the underscore at the end of "pcap_lookupdev_", then it's an undefined reference because it doesn't exist.  The routine is named "pcap_lookupdev", with no underscore at the end.

Comment: @GuyHarris I use this code: dev = pcap_lookupdev(errbuf);

Comment: @GuyHarris and I really don't understand why linker see function with underscore at the end.